# Ruby net-sftp changes the forwardtick for an interrogation symbol on the remote server

Tags: ruby, net-sftp

Hello im using the gem net-sftp to upload a list of files, the upload proceess works as expected but when I upload a file that has a forwardtick on the name the forwardtick is changed on the remote server by a **'?'**

Code

```
    local_file = 'C:/Users/UserA/Documents/RubyProjects/test/The Posesión.pdf'
    remote_file = '/home/UserA/test/The Posesión.pdf'
    sftp.upload!(local_file, remote_file)do |event, uploader, *args|
      case event
      when :open then
        puts "          Upload file: #{args[0].remote}"
      when :put then
        #puts "          Writing #{args[2].length} bytes to #{args[0].remote} starting at #{args[1]}"
      when :close then
        # args[0] : file metadata
        puts "          Upload finished with #{args[0].remote}"
      when :mkdir then
        # args[0] : remote path name
        puts "          Creating dir #{args[0]}"
      when :finish then
        upcount = upcount + 1
      end
    end
```

Example

Local file name: **The Posesión.pdf**

Remote Result:   **The Posesi?n.pdf**

Does anybody knows a way to avoid this behavior?

**Update**

I tested the same code but in a different sftp server (windows) and I got an error maybe this is a bug?

**incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8**

Comment: Maybe your remote server doesn't support that character in filenames?

Comment: It does, I already tested this with a desktop sftp client application

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: Show some more code, are `local_file` and `remote_file` both correct?  How are you building those strings?

Comment: I edited the post and thats the block of code that I use to upload the file

Comment: I tested the same code in a different server and now I got an error related to character encoding I updated the post.